# I want to do a loop that posts a tweet every 24 hours

Tags: python, twitter, while-loop, bots

**My question is how can I automate it to run this code every 24 hours, this code is nothing more than a Twitter bot that I want every 24 hours to send a web link to, it sends just one and stops run but I wanted it to be running, and when it gives 24 hours it sends another photo.**

```
import tweepy
import logging
from source import sourceimg
from config import create_api
import time
import glob
import random
import os

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)

def postKasumi(api):
    logger.info("Generating image...")
    randomNum = random.randint(0,len(sourceimg)-1)
    logger.info("Uploading image...")
    api.update_status("#Anime " + sourceimg.get(randomNum))
    logger.info("Done!")

def main():
    api = create_api()
    postKasumi(api)
    logger.info("Waiting...")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: set up a cronjob

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use a while loop with python's built in [sleep](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_sleep.htm) command:

```
import time

...

def main():
    while True:
        api = create_api()
        postKasumi(api)
        logger.info("Waiting...")
        time.sleep(24 * 60 * 60) #Sleep for 24 hours
```

However, this has some disadvantages. For one thing, you have to keep this script running on your computer forever. For another thing, your computer goes probably goes to sleep by default after a period of inactivity. When it does, your script will stop running. If you're using macOS, you can get around this using
the terminal command [caffeinate](https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-stop-your-mac-from-sleeping-using-the-command-line--mac-50905).

It might be better to just run your script every 24 hours. A good way to do this is with [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) (I believe its only available on mac and linux).

For instance, adding this line to your crontab file will run your script every 24 hours.

```
1 0 * * * python replace/this/with/path/to/your/script/script.py
```

You can edit your crontab with the terminal command `crontab -e`.